# Define the equivalence relation $R$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ associated with the function $f(x) = x^2 - 2x$. Write equivalence classes and quotient set.

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

> Define the equivalence relation $R$ on  $\mathbb{Z}$ associated with the function $f(x) = x^2 - 2x$. Write equivalence classes and quotient set.

I guessed $x^2-2x = y^2 - 2y$ then doing some math I got $x = y$ and $y = 2 - x$. Then, I guessed the $C[1]$ is the 'rare' class, since it only has $[1]$ in its set. However, I don't know how to express the classes and the quotient set correctly, can someone give me some examples please?

Comment: What does it mean for an equivalence relation to be "associated" with a function?  Is the idea that $xRy \iff f(x)=f(y)$?

Comment: @RobertShore yes, that's how my university profressor introduces us $xRy ⟺ f(x) = f(y) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider $x$ a fixed integer. Then $x\sim y$ if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$. If we solve this quadratic equation in terms of $y$ we get

$$y=1\pm(x-1).$$

So the equivalence classes are of the form $[y]=\{y,2-y\}$. The quotient set is naturally identified with the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dots\}$ via the map sending $[y]$ to the unique positive integer in the equivalence class $[y]$ (Draw a picture of the equivalence classes and notice the symmetry around 1).

Comment: Sorry @Mentos , how did you get that equation $y  = 1±(x-1)$ ?

Comment: We fix $x$ and solve the equation $y^2-2y-(x^2-2x)=0$ for $y$. The solutions are $$y= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ where $a=1$, $b=-2$, and $c=-x^2+2x$.